# ScriptEditor folder missing in Fiddler

Tags: 14.04, wine, gedit

Customize Rules is not working in Fiddler web debugging proxy. Maybe it is not able find the editor for itself. See below screenshot for more information.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ScriptEditor folder is missing, there is no `FSE2.exe` file. So when I changed the path of the "FiddlerScript Editor" to "gedit", it worked. Now I am able to customize rules in gedit. See below Screenshot for more details.

[image: Screenshot of options]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)